# Why my wiki is always in loading ?

Tags: django

I have used django-wiki to build my personal wiki.

But when I launch the wiki, I find that it always displays the contents are in loading. Here is the url of my wiki:

[This is my wiki url](http://101.200.42.70:8080/)

Can anybody tell me how to solve the problem ?

[This the wiki loading state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Cf7.png)

Thanks a lot

Comment: The hyperlink: http://101.200.42.70:8080/ loads completely. Are you sure it's not an issue with your internet connection? You can always inspect element(network tab) in your browser and check which file(s) is not loading successfully.

Comment: Dear sir , maybe I don't describe the problem clearly. You can see the wiki loading state . It displays that there are something in loading.

Comment: As I said, the page: http://101.200.42.70:8080/ loads completely in my browser. Probably the issue resides somewhere else. Go to inspect element in your browser and check your network tab. You'll find all the files that the page brings along there only. You can the see which file isn't loading completely.

Comment: I have checked the chrome network tab. But it always displays that there is a circle rotating in the tab just like the image which I have shown.

Comment: I'm certain that it's not an issue with your django project. As I can see, there are 13 files(html, cs and JavaScript) which are requested and all of them reached successfully. This is probably an issue with your net connection or something else.

Comment: What I am confused is that there is always a circle rotating in the chrome tab just like  the image which I have shown.

Comment: Go to inspect element in Chrome and check the network tab. There you will see some files being loaded. Check if any of the files don't have a status = 200 there. The loading indicator in the tab indicates that there is one or more file that isn't loaded completely.